# ESP32 task priority with respect to main loop

Tags: esp32, freertos

The function `xTaskCreate` allows to specify a `uxPriority` number, higher for higher priority as specified at https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html.

But how is this priority considered with respect to the main loop, e.g.:

```
void myTask(void *p) {
//
// Doing stuff...
//
}

void init() {

xTaskCreate(myTask, "myStuff", 8*1024, NULL, 1, NULL); // Priority 1 or any other number.

}

void app_main() {
    
    init();


    while (1) { 
    //
    // **myTaskMain** doing other stuff.
    //
    }
}
```

What will have high priority? The function **myTask** running via xTaskCreate or **myTaskMain** running inside the main loop?

Comment: Finally vTaskStartScheduler is called in main() which doesn’t return. After that there only FreeRTOS tasks running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html#background-tasks) table in de documentation, the app_main task has priority 1, so in your example the tasks will have the same priority.

Another way to get the priority of the app_main task is by calling `uxTaskPriorityGet(NULL)` (docs [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos_idf.html#_CPPv417uxTaskPriorityGetK12TaskHandle_t)) from app_main.
If you want to change the priority of the app_main task you can do that by calling `vTaskPrioritySet(NULL, uxNewPriority)` (docs [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos_idf.html#_CPPv416vTaskPrioritySet12TaskHandle_t11UBaseType_t)) from app_main.

Comment: Yes, thank you I found where app_main is defined and a task with priority 1 is launched https://github.com/esphome/esphome/blob/ccffbfd3ae8be5f535701e427de58a935af58f1d/esphome/components/esp32/core.cpp#L73

Comment: That is not the source code of the ESP-IDF, that's here https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/178b122c145c19e94ac896197a3a4a9d379cd618/components/freertos/port/port_common.c#L82-L84

Comment: Apologies, I just copied the link without checking. My point is that `app_main` is actually a task pinned to core 0 with priority 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is more than incomplete. Normaly "doing other stuff" is just there looping.

Maiby this simple program wil help you to schedule 2 tasks:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pico/stdlib.h"

#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "FreeRTOSConfig.h"
#include "task.h"

void GreenLEDTask(void *param)
{
    while (true) {
        printf("Green ON\n");
        vTaskDelay(1000);
        
        printf("Green OFF\n");
        vTaskDelay(1000);
    }
}

void RedLEDTask(void *param)
{
    while (true) {
        printf("    RED ON\n");
        vTaskDelay(100);
        
        printf("    RED OFF\n");
        vTaskDelay(100);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    stdio_init_all();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Wait %d\n", i);
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
    TaskHandle_t gLEDtask = NULL;
    TaskHandle_t rLEDtask = NULL;

    uint32_t status = xTaskCreate(
                    GreenLEDTask,
                    "Green LED",
                    1024,
                    NULL,
                    tskIDLE_PRIORITY,
                    &gLEDtask);

    uint32_t status2 = xTaskCreate(
                     RedLEDTask,
                     "Red LED",
                     1024,
                     NULL,
                     1,
                     &rLEDtask);

        vTaskStartScheduler();
    
        for( ;; )
        {
            //should never get here
        }
        printf("Cannot reach, end of main\n");
    }
```

The output will generate something like:
Green ON
RED OFF
RED ON
RED OFF
RED ON
RED OFF
RED ON
RED OFF
RED ON
RED OFF
RED ON
Green OFF
RED OFF
RED ON
RED OFF
RED ON
RED OFF
RED ON
RED OFF
RED ON
RED OFF

Comment: The question was about the priority of app_main in ESP32. Your code is not for ESP32. Also the red and green xTasks you used are not running in main. Moreover AFAIK shared core time is possible within tasks of the same priority so your program may reach the end. That depends on the scheduler implementation.